# Possible questions on testing on hypothesis in A/B testing for a position of a data scientist (EDITED)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, nonparametric, gradient-descent, ab-test

What are some possible machine learning and statistics questions on the subject of  A/B testing for a position of a data scientist in Ad Tech industry working in retargeting? I'm interviewing for such a position in 2 days.

To be more specific, A/B testing includes testing of hypothesis, so I'd guess the basic theory of testing of hypothesis, including p-value, level of significance, type I and II errors, power of tests, Neyman-Pearson criterion etc. are all included. Is there anything else should I go through?

On a different note, from the wikipidea page of A/B testing-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing, it appears that it only involves statistics but not much machine learning, although I'm sure that's not true. So, what topics of machine learning can be directly connected with A/B testing, and what would be some sample questions?

Comment: I would ask discussion questions on reddit